# Why is this apt-cache dumpavail with overrides not working?

Tags: debian, apt

I am trying to list available packages from a remote repository **without accessing /etc/apt or /var**.The following command doesn't return anything and exits with code zero.

```
apt-cache dumpavail -o Dir::Etc=tmp/ -o Dir::Cache=tmp/ -o Dir::State=tmp/
```

The command seems correct as per [docs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/apt-cache.8.html). Any idea what I am missing or how I could do it differently?
I have my sources.list under /tmp with contents:

```
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
```

and the current apt config is default

```
$apt-config dump
...
Dir "/";
Dir::State "var/lib/apt/";
Dir::State::lists "lists/";

Dir::State::cdroms "cdroms.list";
Dir::State::mirrors "mirrors/";
Dir::State::extended_states "extended_states";
Dir::State::status "/var/lib/dpkg/status";
Dir::Cache "var/cache/apt/";
Dir::Cache::archives "archives/";
Dir::Cache::srcpkgcache "srcpkgcache.bin";
Dir::Cache::pkgcache "pkgcache.bin";
Dir::Etc "etc/apt/";
Dir::Etc::sourcelist "sources.list";
Dir::Etc::sourceparts "sources.list.d";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-cache dumpavail` reads from `/var/lib/apt/lists` — essentially, it does `cat /var/lib/apt/lists/*_Packages`. In fact, the whole `apt-cache` utility is designed to operate on the locally-cached data, it never queries the network.

You need to run `apt-get` first, and make sure you have set a cache directory where it can operate.

```
dir_cache=$(mktemp -d)
mkdir "$dir_cache/etc" "$dir_cache/var" "$dir_cache/state"
echo 'deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted' >"$dir_cache/etc/apt/sources.list"
apt-get update -o Dir::Etc="$dir_cache/etc" -o Dir::Cache="$dir_cache/var" -o Dir::State="$dir_cache/state"
apt-cache dumpavail -o Dir::Etc="$dir_cache/etc" -o Dir::Cache="$dir_cache/var" -o Dir::State="$dir_cache/state"
rm -r "$dir_cache"
```

Comment: thanks. are you aware of a stateless utility/command that ignores local cache and queries the network instead?

Comment: @bagheera No, the APT tools tend to operate on the local databases. I think the best solution for you is to use the APT tools with a separate database. You could cobble something up with `wget http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/…/Packages.bz2` but that's less robust. Alternatively, [Debian](http://packages.debian.org/) and [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) have online interfaces to query their package database.

Comment: @Giles. thanks. I want to write a deb package poller plugin for a CI server. The package and repo to poll will be specified by the user. Are you aware of any existing library or client for this? e.g. for RHEL/centos/Fedora I can use repoquery to poll rpm packages in a yum repo.

Comment: @bagheera I would use the web interfaces. I don't think there's an API, but they're dead easy to scrape.

Comment: ```apt-cache dumpavail``` isn't listing older versions of packages, while the files in ```/var/lib/apt/lists/*_Packages``` do.